# Flex mobile app: Soft keyboard doesn't fire when Bluetooth scanner is connected

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, bluetooth, keyboard, adobe

After upgrading to Android 7, Flex mobile app doesn't open Soft keyboard when Bluetooth scanner is connected.
Flex IOS app has the same behaviour